# C++11 Optimization of empty function passed as a callback

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, callback

I have a function template:

```
template <class ReportFunc>
void func (ReportFunc report_func)
{
    for (/* ... */)
    {
         do_something (a, b);
         report_func (a, b, c);
         do_something_else (b, c);
    }
}
```

It is sometimes desirable to call func() without any ReportFunc, i.e. the loop just calls do_something() and do_something_else() and nothing else. If I write an overload of f() which doesn't take a ReportFunc parameter, I'll have to duplicate f()'s implementation code, just removing the line which calls report_func().

I have several functions of this kind - sometimes I want to call them with a ReportFunc, sometimes without it. So I'd like to avoid all the code duplication. If I pass an empty lambda or void or something like this, should it make a C++11 compiler generate an instantiation of f() which doesn't call any report_func()? And is it as fast as simply deleting the line which calls report_func() or even an empty lambda has some overhead the compiler doesn't optimize? (in my specific case, I use GCC)

Also: if an empty lambda indeed does that, and I change the function f()'s return type to be ReportFunc, i.e. it returns the report_func argument, is it still safe to store the returned value in a variable and call it? (even if it's an empty lambda? so calling it is theoretically possible, it simply means nothing really happens)

Comment: Pass it a function object with an empty inline `operator()`. A normal empty inline function should work too.

Comment: @n.m. What if I pass an empty lambda, will it be as fast? I'm asking because it makes the code look better: the lambda is defined where it's used and not somewhere else in the code, like a functor would be

Comment: lambdas are little more than syntax sugar for a normal functor -- they should behave the same perf-wise. As always, try it and see :)

Comment: Oh sorry it was my mistake. I misread your code. Passing an object or a function probably won't work at all (that is, no optimization will be done).

Comment: @n.m. why not? the compiler will know on compile-time that the empty operator() will be called, so it can avoid the call and make it as fast as if there wouldn't be a call at all

Comment: Mmm... Maybe an object will work and a function will not. Need to check generated assembly.

Comment: A function will work with recent versions of GCC that optimize indirect calls when the function address is a compile-time constant, e.g. you call `func( &doNothing )` rather than `func( some_func_ptr )` where `some_func_ptr` is a variable that has a value set somewhere else.

Comment: I have just checked with g++ and it optimizes out everything, the lambda, the object and (with -O3) the function too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass an empty functor.

As long as you have optimization turned on the compiler will instantiate the template, inline the (empty) call to the functor, and so do nothing. It should optimize away to nothing, don't bother with metaprogramming to try and remove the call.

I won't swear that G++ optimizes away a "do nothing" lambda in the same way, but it should do, because the type is known and its function call operator is inline and known to be empty.

Using a lambda has no inherent overhead, it's just syntactic sugar for declaring an object type with an `operator()` and creating a temporary of that type. There's quite a lot of work needed for the compiler front-end to do all that, but once the type exists the optimizer should treat it exactly the same as a user-defined struct that does the same thing.  For that reason it's safe to return it too, it's just an instance of an object type, like a user-defined function object.

Comment: I agree, if it works with a simple empty functor, why bother with metaprogramming mess? Another question: even if the empty lamda or empty operator() takes parameters (it has to, because it has a required signature), the compiler will just ignore the parameters and optimize them away?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your lambda does not capture any local variable by reference, it is safe to return it and call later (for an empty lambda it will be just a callable object with no member variables, thus safe to copy and return).

As for the call elimination, it is up to your compiler to figure out that the lambda does nothing and remove the call.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach, it's simple implementation, no code duplication, and eases the pain of having to pass an empty lambda at each call site:

```
struct EmptyParam
{
  void operator()(int a, int b, int c){}
};

template <class ReportFunc>
void func (ReportFunc report_func)
{
  int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
  for (/* ... */)
  {
    do_something (a, b);
    report_func (a, b, c);
    do_something_else (b, c);
  }
}

void func()
{
  func<EmptyParam>(EmptyParam());
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  func([](int,int,int){});
  func();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: For completeness, below is the version that avoids the call to report_func altogether. For your particular case, it's not really more optimal then the first solution I proposed, just another way of doing things. Personally, I'd go with the above solution though:

```
struct EmptyParam{};

template <class ReportFunc>
struct CallReportFunc
{
  static void Call(const ReportFunc & report_func, int a, int b, int c)
  {
    report_func (a, b, c);
  }
};

template <>
struct CallReportFunc<EmptyParam>
{
  static void Call(const EmptyParam &/*report_func*/, int /*a*/, int /*b*/, int /*c*/)
  {
    // do nothing
  }
};

template <class ReportFunc>
void func (ReportFunc report_func)
{
  int a =0,b =0,c=0;
  for (;true;)
  {
    CallReportFunc<ReportFunc>::Call(report_func, a, b, c);
  }
}

void func()
{
  func<EmptyParam>(EmptyParam());
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  func([](int,int,int){});
  func();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if I just pass a functor with an empty operator()? Won't the compiler be able to eliminate the call (since the operator() does nothing anyway)? Or an empty lambda? It would be even more simple

Comment: @fr33domlover you mean `func([](){});`? The template won't compile because it is trying to call the report_func with three parameters, yet it takes none. Having a func() overload with no parameters is cleaner in my opinion. If you mean `func([](int,int,int){});` then still `func();` is more readable.

Comment: I mean an operator() or a lambda with correct parameters but empty function body. I disagree, having an overload means code duplication, I already have that and I want to avoid the duplication

Comment: @Zadirion, so you pass it `func([](const TypeA&, const TypeB&, const TypeC&){})` instead

Comment: @fr33domlover there is no code duplication in the code I posted above. the `void func()` overload is a wrapper over the templated `func()`, the only one holding your logic. No duplication.

Comment: @Zadirion, but it's **a lot** more code than the original version

Comment: @JonathanWakely having `func([](const TypeA&, const TypeB&, const TypeC&){})` instead of `func()` at each call site is **a lot** more code.

Comment: So define `struct Noop { template<class... T> void operator()(T&&...) const { } };`  and use `Noop{}` at each call site (and anywhere else it might be useful), that's still less code than your specializations. Let the compile optimize the code, spend your time writing the useful stuff.

Comment: You are putting the burden on your callers by having them know about your Noop{} instead of the intuitive way of omitting an unneeded parameter.
Has nothing to do with the compiler, and the `func` overload is a simple one liner. Way cleaner than what you propose.

Comment: @Zadirion you're not, because the Noop is the default value of the report_func parameter, just don't specify an argument

Comment: unfortunately, default values in templated functions are not used in the template deduction process. You still have to call it like this: func<Noop>(). So your solution doesn't work as advertised...

Comment: I didn't know that, but the solution is simple: define an overload func() which calls func<Noop>() ...

Comment: No, you suggested a template specialization that doesn't call the functor, that's not the same as an overload that calls the function with an empty functor. And in C++11 you can have default template arguments on function templates.

Comment: `void func()
{
  func<EmptyParam>(EmptyParam());
}`
That's an overload calling the templated `func` with an empty functor, and is what you would have found in my answer if you had actually read it. I see no template specialization. Care to point it?